# Find all sub strings separated by dot in a string?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a large string in which I need to find all the presences 
of a sub-string from the pattern:

```
[Word][Dot][Word][Dot]...[Word]
```

I'm having some troubles, especially with the repeatedly `[Word][Dot][Word]` pattern

Here's the string:

```
"a.a b..b c.c.c d. .e ff g...g hh.h i.i..i"
```

and here's my current pattern:

```
\S+[.{1}]\S+
```

The `Matcher.find()` return those sub strings:

```
[0,3] a.a  
[4,8] b..b - shouldn't match  
[9,14] c.c.c  
[24,29] g...g  - shouldn't match  
[30,34] hh.h  
[35,41] i.i..i  - shouldn't match
```

I can't make it ignore the b,g,i sub strings

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj As I wrote above, it shouldn't find the b,g,i sub strings. this should be the output: [0,3] a.a  
[9,14] c.c.c  
[30,34] hh.h

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: `\S` matches any non-white space character which is causing issue.

Comment: By the way, `{1}` is wholly superfluous. Any token is matched exactly once unless otherwise specified.

Comment: `j..j.j` should it return the result `j.j`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be more explicit:

```
[^\s.]+(?:\.[^\s.]+)+(?!\S)
```

**Explanation:**

```
[^\s.]+   # Match one or more characters exceopt dot or whitespace
(?:       # Start a non-capturing group
 \.       # Match a dot
 [^\s.]+  # Match one or more characters exceopt dot or whitespace
)+        # Repeat as often as necessary
(?!\S)    # Make sure we don't stop before a non-whitespace character
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/jK3vS8/1).

```js
subject = "a.a b..b c.c.c d. .e ff g...g hh.h i.i..i";
result = subject.match(/[^\s.]+(?:\.[^\s.]+)+(?!\S)/g);
document.write(result)
```

Comment: @itoor: Thanks for accepting this answer, but Casimir raised an important point in his comment to your question - my solution would match `j.j` if the substring `j..j.j` occurred in your input. Normally, one would guard against this using a lookbehind assertion, but JavaScript doesn't support those. A workaround would be to prepend `(?:^|\s)` to the regex (and then later trim an eventual whitespace character from the start of each match).